# Windows Azure Management Cache Usage Statistics

Tags: azure, azure-storage

With the old version of Windows Azure Management there was a way to check the azure cache usage.  In the services you could see the current usage and last and this month's peak usage.  With the update of the Windows Azure Management App I don't see anywhere to find this data.  Is it hiding somewhere that I just can't find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the reasons why MS did not move that functionality to the new portal is that they favour in-role caching over shared caching.

> Caching on Windows Azure roles supports additional features, such as
>   high availability, regions, notifications, and multiple named caches.
>   Because it is part of your cloud service, Caching on roles should also
>   have improved performance over Shared Caching ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh697522.aspx#C_BKMK_FAQ9))

However, you can alwasy go back to the old portal (Silverlight version) which is still functional. In order to do that you go to top-left menu and chose *Previous portal* from there.

[image: Previous Portal]